# Which repository contains LWP::Parallel::UserAgent?

Tags: windows, perl, cpan, perl-ppm

I need to install [LWP::Parallel::UserAgent](http://www.metacpan.org/module/LWP::Parallel::UserAgent) to run on Windows environment, I used ActivePerl 5.10. I search on Google but did not find any information about repo for this package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to find a module (or which distribution a module lives in), always turn to CPAN, not Google.  Go to search.cpan.org and type the module name into the textbox and click search.  You will see results that look like this:

> [LWP::Parallel::UserAgent](http://search.cpan.org/~marclang/ParallelUserAgent-2.57/lib/LWP/Parallel/UserAgent.pm)
>   A class for parallel User Agents
>   [ParallelUserAgent-2.57](http://search.cpan.org/~marclang/ParallelUserAgent-2.57/) `****` ([1 Reviews](http://cpanratings.perl.org/d/ParallelUserAgent)) - 09 Feb 2004 - [Marc Langheinrich](http://search.cpan.org/~marclang/)

The first link is to the documentation for the module you were searching for.  The second is a link to the distribution the module is in (commonly they have the same name, but as we can see here they may differ), the third link is to what people have to say about this module, and the fourth is to the Author's CPAN page, which will contain all of the modules the author has uploaded to CPAN and her or his contact information.

From this search information we can see that the LWP::Parallel::UserAgent is in the ParallelUserAgent distribution.

Comment: pmtools (http://search.cpan.org/dist/pmtools/) is handy - a large number of quick command line tools to show installed modules, path to a module, version of installed module, etc (see the README for more information on each script).
not sure if it will work with the Windows Perl distributions though?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see what ppm packages are available, go to [Kobes Search](http://cpan.uwinnipeg.ca/htdocs/faqs/cpan-search.html). There you'll see that [ParallelUserAgent](http://cpan.uwinnipeg.ca/search?query=paralleluseragent&mode=dist) is currently only available for perl 5.8 in the repositories known to Kobes. I see a lot of [test failures on Windows](http://matrix.cpantesters.org/?dist=ParallelUserAgent+2.57) so I kind of doubt that it'll work there anyway, but it's a pure perl module, so all you really have to do is copy the files from the [CPAN distribution](http://search.cpan.org/dist/ParallelUserAgent/) to see for yourself whether it works or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it from [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/~marclang/ParallelUserAgent-2.57/lib/LWP/Parallel/UserAgent.pm).

Comment: i think he wants a prebuild windows *binary* / ppm, which you don't get from CPAN, but from a PPM Repository &lt;http://ppm4.activestate.com/&gt;

Answer (score 0):

The magic CPAN index file that maps a module to a distribution that contains it is *modules/02packages.details.txt.gz*. If you're ever just stuck with a copy of CPAN with access to sites such as [CPAN Search](http://search.cpan.org), that's the place to look.

Also, the `cpan -D` command will tell you:

```
% cpan -D LWP::Parallel::UserAgent
LWP::Parallel::UserAgent
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
        (no description)
        M/MA/MARCLANG/ParallelUserAgent-2.57.tar.gz
        Installed: 
        CPAN:      undef  Not up to date
        Marc Langheinrich (MARCLANG)
        marclang@cpan.org
```